# Как проверить на совпадение данных при записи в файл

Tags: java

Как сделать, чтобы можно было проверить id на совпадение, и выдать ошибку интересует только id

```
 public static final String FILE_PATH = "developers.txt";

public void create(Developer developer) {
    Writer writer = null;
    String str = developer.getId() + "," + developer.getFirstName() + "," + developer.getLastName() + "," + developer.getSpecialty() + "," + developer.getSalary();
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(FILE_PATH, true);
        writer.write(str + '\n');
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: На совпадение с чем?

Comment: Чтобы проверить совадение с данными, которые уже есть в файле - необходимо файл прочитать, например в Set, далее, всё станет очевидным - сет не может содержать два идентичных значения, и сет имеет метод contains, который за максимально возможное время определит, есть ли элемент в коллекции. Так же, замечу, что вы не закрываете файл, хотя, это не относится к теме вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай сначала множество `Developer` используя `HashSet<Developer>`. Данное множество само удалит дубликаты, если вы переопределили метод `hashCode` у класса `Developer`.
К примеру, вы можете переопределить метод `hashCode` следующим образом:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id;
}
```

Затем создайте множество:

```
HashSet<Developer> tests = new HashSet<>();
```

И добавьте в него все объекты класса `Developer`, которые хотите записать в файл.
После добавления все объекты класса `Developer`, будут добавлены в множество, кроме дубликатов.

Однако, будьте внимательны, после переопределения метода hashCode у вас могут измениться другие части кода, в которых вы используете этот класс.

Оптимальным решением будет - создание дополнительных методов, собирающий список всех не повторяющихся объектов.

```
private List<Developer> getDeveloperList(List<Developer> totalDeveloperList){
    if(totalDeveloperList == null || totalDeveloperList.isEmpty()){
        return totalDeveloperList;
    }

    List<Developer> developerList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Developer developer : totalDeveloperList){
        if(!hasDeveloper(developerList, developer)){
            developerList.add(developer);
        }
    }

    return developerList;
}

private boolean hasDeveloper(List<Developer> developerList, Developer checkableDeveloper){
    if(developerList == null || developerList.isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }

    for(Developer developer : developerList){
        if(developer.getId() == checkableDeveloper.getId()){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```